# How to grep on gdb print

Tags: debugging, unix, gdb

Is there a way to grep on the output of print command in gdb? In my case, I am debugging a core dump using gdb and the object I am debugging contains hell lots of elements.

I am finding it difficult to look for a matching attribute i.e:

```
(gdb) print *this | grep <attribute>
```

Comment: Then you want this patch: http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2011-07/msg00572.html

Comment: The main problem with this syntax is that the | character is a valid c operator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> (gdb) print *this | grep

The "standard" way to achieve this is to use `Meta-X gdb` in `emacs`.

An alternative:

```
(gdb) set logging on
(gdb) print *this
(gdb) set logging off
(gdb) shell grep attribute gdb.txt
```

The patch mentioned by cnicutar sure looks attractive compared to the above. I am guessing the reason it (or its equivalent) was never submitted is that most GDB maintainers use `emacs`, and so don't have this problem in the first place.

Comment: @Employed Russian reason: http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2011-07/msg00284.html

Comment: What're you talking about? I am using Emacs, and just tried the `print $rax | grep 41`, it says «No symbol "grep"». If you does meant that emacs allows to search, it is surely not the native grep. The grep could be used in a script, i.e. to make a gdb watchpoint to not stop in a particular function *(that's what I am trying to achieve)*.

Comment: You can overwrite the gdb.txt if you don't want the logging history output :^)

`(gdb) set logging overwrite on`
`(gdb) set logging on`

Answer (score 18):

You can use `pipe` command

```
>>> pipe maintenance info sections | grep .text
 [15]     0x5555555551c0->0x5555555554d5 at 0x000011c0: .text ...

>>> pipe maintenance info sections | grep .text | wc 
      1      10     100
```

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: Available since gdb 9.1. https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2020-02/msg00008.html

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to exploit gdb python. One-liner:

```
gdb λ py ["attribute" in line and print(line) for line in gdb.execute("p *this", to_string=True).splitlines()]
```

Assuming you have enabled history of commands, you can type this just once, and later then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>b.exec</kbd> to pull it out of history. Next simply change `attribute` and `*this` per your requirements.

---

You can also make this as simple as this:

```
gdb λ grep_cmd "p *this" attribute
```

For that just add the following to your `.gdbinit` file:

```py
py
class GrepCmd (gdb.Command):
    """Execute command, but only show lines matching the pattern
    Usage: grep_cmd <cmd> <pattern> """

    def __init__ (_):
        super ().__init__ ("grep_cmd", gdb.COMMAND_STATUS)

    def invoke (_, args_raw, __):
        args = gdb.string_to_argv(args_raw)
        if len(args) != 2:
            print("Wrong parameters number. Usage: grep_cmd <cmd> <pattern>")
        else:
            for line in gdb.execute(args[0], to_string=True).splitlines():
                if args[1] in line:
                    print(line)

GrepCmd() # required to get it registered
end
```

Comment: +1 Adding GrepCmd to ~/.gdbinit works great for simple filtering like (gdb) grep_cmd 'help all' 'Print backtrace'

Comment: That is pretty neat. By any chance, would you know a way to highlight the "grep"ped words.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but since I found it looking to do the same thing I thought I would add to Hi-Angel's answer to say you can highlight the search term, in the python output, in a red colour by replacing the print line with the one below:

```py
print(line.replace(args[1], "\033[91m"+args[1]+"\033[0m"))
```

This just uses `ascii escape` commands for the colour, so should work on Linux and Windows terminal, and you can easily change the colour.

*Sorry, don't have enough rep to add this as a comment.*