# Does GDB support displaying contents as pointer typed values?

Tags: pointers, gdb, windbg, addressing

Windbg has a `dpp` command, which interprets values in memory as pointers and prints out the pointer is pointing to. Shown below:

[image: dpp visualized]

My questions is, does GDB has similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the gdb command line you can cast addresses to pointer values.

```
(gdb) list

1   #include <stdio.h>
2   
3   char * m = "this is a test\n";
4        
5   main()
6   {
7      printf("%s",m);
8   }
(gdb) b 7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400531: file example.c, line 7.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/example

Breakpoint 1, main () at example.c:7
7      printf("%s",m);
(gdb) p m
$1 = 0x4005d4 "this is a test\n"
(gdb) p *(char*)0x4005d4
$2 = 116 't'
(gdb) p *(int*)0x4005d4
$3 = 1936287860
(gdb) p *(double**)0x4005d4
$5 = (double *) 0x2073692073696874
```

The last two are rubbish of course since the value is a char *.

The dump command is also useful for looking at hex value.

```
(gdb) x/20c m
0x4005d4:   116 't' 104 'h' 105 'i' 115 's' 32 ' '  105 'i' 115 's' 32 ' '
0x4005dc:   97 'a'  32 ' '  116 't' 101 'e' 115 's' 116 't' 10 '\n' 0 '\000'
0x4005e4:   37 '%'  115 's' 0 '\000'    0 '\000'
```

Comment: That doesn't sound really close. Does GDB support writing scripts?

Comment: Yes.  Here is an example using python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069090/debugger-gdb-evaluate-expression/39132967#39132967